# Automatic check out on Team Foundation Server using SQL Server Managment Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tfs

I have created a project in SSMS and link it to TFS.

When I first created the project a query would check out to me when edited.

However after a re-boot of the PC it is no longer doing this and I have to manually check out to then check back in changes.

Checked in item behaviour are both set at "Check out Automatically"

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Try: Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment

Half way down the screen you have 2 drop-down boxes for Saving and Editing. Set `Editing`to `Check out automatically` and you're done.

Comment: Checked in item behaviour are both set at "Check out Automatically" (edited question to reflect this)